# How to generically type an object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I’ve got an object of settings and want to provide single key-value pairs to a function like so:

```js
const settings = {
  time1: 40 * 60 * 60,
  time2: 10 * 60 * 60,
  breaks: [
    { limit: 6 * 60 * 60, length: 30 * 60 },
    { limit: 9 * 60 * 60, length: 15 * 60 },
  ],
}

// works
function changeSetting1<T extends keyof typeof settings>(details: {key: T, value: typeof settings[T]}): void {
//
}

// doesn't work
type func_details = <T extends keyof typeof settings>{key: T, value: typeof settings[T]}
function changeSetting2(details: func_details): void {

changeSetting1({key: "time1", value: 8 * 60 * 60})
changeSetting2({key: "time1", value: 8 * 60 * 60})
```

While it seems to work when I type it directly at the function, TypeScript complains that there is a `(` expected when I first define the type func_details. What is the correct syntax for doing so?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUoEswHMIwLwwN4CgYYUBbeARgC4YAWABhgCoYA2B5tgGkOOTICZq5dqxFceAIwBO8AIYBrCNQDaPIrhgAbPsijUWTUYa5b46KAAtqAZjEMAvtyLqtOvTACcxu51PmrMOQArN4wjjwAutz2%20PgA9HEwAO4gUor4AGYArmDAKOAwwBay6PAAyogo6OQAPAAqMPAAHlBmACaY8vAAniAZxN0ADvB9cJWoGAB8ABRtiLLImkp4Xd3Udb4AbrKaWfDUUEMj-QhIExDKdRH2AJTUmyDIbXjxcfgxrzBtIPAQYADksBSaXwh2GMGyuQA%20nMoAsltgYPVGi12p0eqMwccxmd0BBJrhVustjs9gcjqNTlUMJdrpkcnlkAUiiU0OVxuh%20LN5otlpDgDCeUs7jAHk8XvgWaUKri0ORpoSetQAESkCjKkm7fYwAAcoQ4dFukuK0o5aC5irWMFVfHVmrJuv1oluQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a syntax error. The type definition should be:

```
type func_details<T extends keyof typeof settings> = {key: T, value: typeof settings[T]};
```

Secondly, since the function accepts an argument with a generic type, the function itself must have a generic argument that satisfies the `extends keyof typeof settings` condition.

```
function changeSetting2<T extends keyof typeof settings>(details: func_details<T>): void {
  // [...]
}
```